# An item is originally packed or packaged?

Tags: expressions, word-usage, differences

I'm about to list a brand new CD on eBay. The listing assumes a condition note where I want to point out, that the item is brand new and *originally **packed***.

Google Translate suggests to change the above wording to *originally **packaged***. This is embarrassing, as I thought that "packaging" is actually a bit of a work, means: to put an item into a package, protecting case, box, etc.

When a manufacturer overwraps a small thing (i.e. a book, a CD, a postcard) with a plastic foil, he/she normally packs it, right? Not packages?

How would you correctly say in English *The item is originally packed/packaged* assuming it might not neccessarily be factory-sealed. It is just originally wrapped.

**UPDATE** (inspired by comments)

I understand the trick with *a noun* (*...in its original packaging*), but I wonder if there is an expression with a verb in passive voice. For example in German we normally say "original verpackt". The *'t'* at the end of a verb means the passive voice. Germans even have an abbreviation *OVP*. In Russian I would also use the passive voice.

So the question is: originally packed or originally packaged?
Unless both forms are not valid and won't be correctly understood.

Comment: The standard construction is "*in its original packaging*", i.e. using *packaging* as a noun rather than a verb applied to the CD.

Comment: @DanBron If you add a definition of the noun *packaging*, it think yours is an answer.

Comment: FWIW - Ebay has its own set of condition codes with very specific meanings.  In your case, "New" is the condtion indicating that the original packaging is intact.  http://pages.ebay.com/help/sell/item-condition.html#dvd

Comment: @DanBron, so the correct usage is _The CD is originally packaged_? My point is that the CD can still be new and be listed as new even it it had been repacked (for example: the jewel case was broken and the replaced). What I want to emphasize that the item has neither been opened nor its case was replaced.

Comment: @InterfaceUnknown As I said, the correct (common, standard, idiomatic, whatever you want to call it) description is "The CD is in its original packaging".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others have noted, the correct term is *original packaging*, which indicates the packaging has neither been opened nor replaced.

The word *original* is defined as "existing from the beginning" and the word *packaging* is defined as "materials used to wrap or protect goods", so *original packaging* means that the materials that existed from the beginning are used to wrap or protect the goods, i.e., the *original packaging*.

To an English-speaking audience, *originally packed* and *originally packaged* would both seem like incomplete statements ("originally packed *where*?", "originally packaged *where*?").

In the context of an eBay listing, if you say a CD is new and "in its original packaging", or you simply state "Original packaging.", it will be understood that the packaging for the CD has not been repaired or replaced.